# The date data in Excel does not match the data in spyder ide

Tags: python, excel, csv, datetime

when I open the csv file with excel, the last datetime appears as **9.04.2021 17:16.** csv file like this

[image]

but when I read the csv file with spyder, the last datetime is **2021-04-12 16:45:18**

also number of rows in Excel **1048575**

number of rows in Spyder **1106417**

I'm reading the csv file like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv('log_file.csv',delimiter=';')
```

is there a way to resolve the discrepancy here ?

> UPTADE: the problem stems from excel's row limit. Excel rowlimit: 1.048.576, my csv row count: 1.106.417

Comment: What is the date field if you open the csv in a text editor (notepad)? It might give a clue.

Comment: This sounds like two separate issues - datetime and the number of rows. Try to separate them. Check the file in a text editor, as @Stefan suggests (not in Excel !). How does the date look there? How many lines has the file there?

Comment: When I open it with notepad, the csv data in the date column looks like this: 2021-03-01 07:16:54.0  The " .0 " expression is unnecessary.

Comment: don't worry about the fractional seconds (" .0 " expression). Are we talking about the same line? I mean, `2021-03-01 07:16:54.0` in notepad, how does exactly that date look like in Excel, how does it look like after you import it into the pandas dataframe?

Comment: I think I found it. I'm stuck on excel's row limit.

Comment: Mental note for the future: Excel is *not* CSV.